# Unable to delete objects from Algolia

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, algolia

I have a post object that someone would originally make, then this would trigger a Firebase function to then add it to Algolia for querying later. I am having some issues when removing the object from Algolia when a user deletes a post. The function is being triggered in Firebase, but it is "updating" the post and not deleting it.

Here are the logs from the Firebase Functions console:

```
onPostWrite: Function execution took 79 ms, finished with status: 'ok'
onPostWrite: Function execution started
onPostWrite: Updated post -Lb3lcmWn1iXAdnbFDmo
```

Here is the code executed for the function:

```
exports.onPostWrite = functions.database.ref('/posts/{postId}').onWrite((snapshot, context) => {
  const index = client.initIndex(ALGOLIA_INDEX_POSTS);
  //When the data is first created...
  if (snapshot.before.exists()) {
    const post = snapshot.before.val();

    post.objectID = context.params.postId;

    console.log('Updated post ', post.objectID);
    return index.saveObject(post);
  }
  //When data has been deleted...
  if (!snapshot.after.exists()) {
    const post = snapshot.before.val();

    post.objectID = context.params.postId;

    console.log('Deleted post ', post.objectID);
    return index.deleteObject(post.objectID);
  }

  if (!snapshot.before.exists()) {
    const post = snapshot.after.val();

    post.objectID = context.params.postId;

    console.log('Created post ', post.objectID);
    return index.saveObject(post);
  }
});
```

As you can tell, it is only executing the "Update" command and not the create or delete command.

I think it may have something to do with my IF statements, but I am not sure. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you log `index.deleteObject(post.objectID);`? Right now you're logging `deleted post <id>`, which won't ever give you any useful telemetry beyond the ID itself. Also, what type of API key are you using to initialize the index?

Comment: I can't log that part of the code because the function never reaches that point. When I go in my app and delete a post, the code for that functionality does not get triggered. That is the question I have. I am also using the Algolia admin API key.

Comment: in that case the problem seems to be with `!snapshot.after.exists()`

Comment: I actually fixed this whole thing by making three separate functions for the create, update, and delete portions. However, this is kinda inefficient and I would like to find out what was wrong here. I'll play around with the `!snapshot.after.exists()` and see if that works.

Comment: yep, let us know if you come across an answer!

Answer (score 1):

You need to switch the order of your `if` statements.

```
// Called onUpdate, a snapshot exists before the update and exists after the update
// Called onDeletion, a snapshot exists before the update and doesn't exist after the update
if (snapshot.before.exists()) {

// Called onDeletion, nothing exists after operation
if (!snapshot.after.exists()) {

// Called onCreate. Nothing existed `before`, but it does now
if (!snapshot.before.exists()) {
```

Because you're returning in each block, your execution stops after the first block even on deletion. I think if you swapped the first two blocks, it'd work as expected:

```
// Called onDelete, nothing exists after operation
if (!snapshot.after.exists()) {

// Called onUpdate, a snapshot exists before the update and exists after the update
// Called onDelete, a snapshot exists before the update and doesn't exist after the update
// Since you've moved a "better" `onDelete` above this, this function will now only be called for onUpdate 
if (snapshot.before.exists()) {

// Called onCreate. Nothing existed `before`, but it does now
if (!snapshot.before.exists()) {
```

Note: You don't really need the last `if` statement since the prior two will catch `delete` and `update` operations, the last is the only other path your code could take. Here's my take on it all:

```
exports.onPostWrite = functions
  .database
  .ref('/posts/{postId}')
  .onWrite((snapshot, context) => {
    const index = client.initIndex(ALGOLIA_INDEX_POSTS);

    // no snapshot.before.exists(), post has been created
    if (!snapshot.before.exists()) {
      const post = snapshot.after.val();
      post.objectID = context.params.postId;

      console.log('Creating post ', post.objectID);
      return index.saveObject(post);
    }

    const post = snapshot.before.val();
    post.objectID = context.params.postId;

    // no snapshot.after.exists(), post has been deleted
    if (!snapshot.after.exists()) {
      console.log('Deleting post ', post.objectID);
      return index.deleteObject(post.objectID);
    }

    // snapshot.before.exists() AND snapshot.after.exists(), post has been updated
    console.log('Updating post ', post.objectID);
    return index.saveObject(post);

  });
```